# Adsense ads strange behaviour on WP website

Tags: wordpress, caching, adsense, cloudflare, w3-total-cache

I have a website which uses w3 total cache and CloudFlare default settings.

The ads were working great for over 4 months

After version 4.8.1 of WordPress (I believe it was ~ 2 weeks ago, from now) I had a minor issue with my ads - they stopped showing only on my home page. Back then I just flushed the cache from w3 total cache, purged it from CloudFlare, deleted my browser cache and enabled 3 page rules.

1st - to bypass the cache of wp-admin* 
2nd - to bypass the cache of wp-json* (for my contact form to work properly)
3rd - to cache everything else, including JS

The ads appeared again. I made a fresh restart of the server, purged CloudFlare and w3 total cache again and everything was working for 10+ days great.

During that time I have been asking several users, friends, from different countries to check if they see the ads and they have confirmed that they do.

Until 2 days ago, when the ads disappeared again.

Not only that. I had 4 ads on the home page (Now removed 2 and left only 2 - 1 in the PHP and 1 in column element, for test purpose, until I fix it):
1. Responsive links type ad inserted in the header (in a div, in the PHP of the theme). The div looks like this div align="center"
2. Responsive Text/Image ad inserted in column elements with my BeTheme's Muffin Builder

Note that I haven't changed the code of the ads in any way during these several months and they have been inserted on my website in the same way.

Today's problem:

1. Ads don't show on mobile at all.
2. Only 1 ad shows on a desktop and it is always the same - Coca-cola advertisement or something like this and the ad doesn't show ad choice icon or the "x" icon like a regular AdSense ad.
3. When I add ?whateverhere the home page opens again but this time shows the ads. 
   Example: mydomain.com/ - no ads, mydomain.com/?ashdfdjaskdh - regular ads

Even so, I see at least 1 ad on the home page I have checked my domain in https://ctrlq.org/sandbox/ just to be sure it is not Page Level Ban from Adsense. It clearly shows that the page is able to display all kinds of ads without problem. Note that on every other page the ads are working also.

What I have tried so far:

1. Checked the ad codes for corruption - all are the same like in my AdSense dashboard. Didn't work.
2. Made new ads - didn't work with them either (I waited for them to become active and they started showing on the other pages).
3. Reversed previous version of WP. Didn't work.
4. Flushed and completely wiped off and deleted the caching plugin + its settings in the htaccess file. Didn't work.
5. Disabled CloudFlare completely. Didn't work.
6. Contacted BeTheme support. They couldn't help.
7. Deleted all the plugins. (Installed them back after it didn't work)
8. Changed the theme to standard wp. (changed it again after)
9. Checked, repaired and optimized the database.
10. Installed a backup of the website from 25th of July. Didn't work.
11. Read tens of topics about this and there are a lot of people experiencing the same problem. In google forums for some - reverting back to old WP version worked, for others changing their sites from www to non www or the oposite worked (havent tested the last but 99% of my backlinks are pointing to the https www version of the site, so if this work I have to make a permanent redirect)

Any tips or possible solutions are more than welcome as I am completly lost now.